# Retrieve from firebase and render in ejs

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, ejs

So I'm basically trying to do a "foreach" loop for my ejs frontend but I can't seem to res.render the snapshot in the server.js. I can't seem to get the variable into the res.render(). I have no problem retrieving the data from firebase FYI.

I've already tried various methods such as moving it in the ref.on etc

```js
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var ref = database.ref('Courses');
    // var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
    ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        });
    });
    res.render('pages/index', {
        ChildData: childData
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, since it may take some time. Instead of waiting for the data to come back from the server, the main code of your app continues straight away. Then when the data is available, your callback is called with that data.

This means that any code that needs the data from the database needs to be *inside* that callback.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var ref = database.ref('Courses');

    ref.once("value", function (snapshot) {
        var childData;
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {    
            childData = childSnapshot.val();
        });
        res.render('pages/index', {
            ChildData:childData
        });    
    });
});
```

The main changes:

- I moved the `res.render` *into* the callback, so that it runs after the data is available.
- I declare the `var childData` before the loop, so that it's also available to the code outside of the loop.
- I use `once` instead of `on`, so that the data is only loaded once.

Comment: thanks, it works! but i replaced var childdata with another variable array. and added a array.push below the childData snapshot

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   var ref = database.ref('Courses');
// var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");

   ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
     snapshot.map(function (childSnapshot) {
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
     });
     res.render('pages/index', {
        ChildData:childData
     });

   });

});
```

Move the response send method inside the callback of `ref.on` and change `forEach` to `map` becuase map is synchronous so it will complete the iterations first and will send the data in response

Comment: it returned snapshot.map is not a function and the childData is not read from the ref.on

Comment: Send snapshot as a response instead of childData

Comment: @mzparacha `snapshot` is a [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot) object, which doesn't have a `map` method. It *does* have a `forEach` method however, so that's what's typically used to loop over it.